# What is the most efficient way of storing language models in NLP applications?

Tags: nlp, n-gram, language-model

How do they usually store and update language models (such as N-gram models)? What kind of structure is the most efficient way for storing these models in databases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common data structures in language models are [tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). You can take a look at [Kenneth Heafield's paper](https://kheafield.com/professional/avenue/kenlm.pdf) on his own language model toolkit [KenLM](https://kheafield.com/code/kenlm/) for more detailed information about the data structures used by his own software and related packages.

Answer (score 1):

For speech recognition and some other applications, it's common to represent n-gram models as finite state transducers. I don't know that FSTs are the most efficient storage structure, but there are very simple (and mathematically clean) ways of combining them with other portions of a speech recognition model.

See the [OpenFST](http://openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/WebHome) library and the [OpenGRM](http://opengrm.org/) tools (built on top of OpenFST) for language-model construction, pruning, evaluation, etc. [Mohri et al., 2002](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1010&context=cis_papers) is a good introduction, along with the other papers linked from the OpenFST and OpenGRM sites.